# Showing the label But sending the id in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am implementing a AJAX autocomplete.
The idea is to render an HTML page to the right side of the input box based on the search terms.

> HTML PART: [and using rails :layout => false]

The page to be rendered looks like the following one, when the search term is *dolore*:

```
{"label":"laboriosam praesentium amet ea et qui non consequatur quod","value":1}
{"label":"aut omnis non quia aut animi","value":2}
{"label":"eveniet pariatur dicta quae ut","value":3}
{"label":"voluptatem ad quaerat aut atque est alias a quo","value":4}
{"label":"dolorem labore nisi natus labore dolorum eum","value":5}
```

---

> AJAX Part: [using AJAX directly insted of autocomplete]

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#title_name').keyup(function(){
      var input = $('#title_name').val();
     if (input.length > 2) {
      $.ajax({
           url: "/search/titles",
           data: "search="+input,
           success: function(msg){
             $("#suggest-title").html(msg);
             $("#suggest-title div .titlelist").mouseover(function(){
               $("#suggest-title div .titlelist").removeClass("search_hover");
               $(this).addClass("search_hover");
             });
             $("#suggest-title .titlelist").click(function(){
              var field_value = $(this).html();
              $("#title_name").val(field_value);
              $("#title_name").append('<input type="hidden" name="title_id" value="5" />');
              $("#suggest-title").remove();
             });
           }
         });
     }
    });
  });
```

---

> TODO: The idea is to show the "label" part to the user on searching but sending the id back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use jqueryui [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)?

Then you could do:

```
var availableTags = [{label:"ActionScript", id:1},{label: "AppleScript", id:2}];
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(evt, ui){
        alert(ui.item.id);
        //post the id to the server
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rmEr7/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer...
But I onlu need the item's id 

> "i.e., title_id"

 when the form is submitted, so that i can build off of that id in the server side.

is there any other way to get the label and value separated other than qutocomplete route?